# Eclipse PDT word completion fails for PHP singleton instances

Tags: php, eclipse, oop, eclipse-pdt, code-completion

I have a basic singleton class, similar to the one shown in the PHP documentation:

```
// Based on "Example #2 Singleton Function" from
// www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php
class Example {
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {
        echo 'I am constructed';
    }

    public static function singleton() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        echo 'This is my method';
    }
}
```

The code I write to get an instance of this class is:

```
$myExample = Example::singleton();
```

Using PDT, if I try to use its word completion to find the method myMethod in this instance, it fails.  That is, if I type the following in the editor:

```
$myExample->
```

And immediately after the "`->`", I press the key combination for word completion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on my computer), Eclipse tells me "No Default Proposals".  I expect to see "`myMethod`" appear as a choice, but it doesn't.

How can I make word completion work?  Do I need to configure Eclipse differently?  Do I need to write my singleton a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are your friend

```
/**
*
* @return Example
*/
public static function singleton() {
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        $c = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $c;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Add the @return annotation to the method docblock and eclipse should recognize that and provide detailed auto-complete choices.

Comment: A-ha!  That works perfectly.  At one point, I wondered if that would make a difference, but I dismissed it and didn't try it.  It seemed too simple.  I'm happy to see that I'm wrong, this time.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @L S No worries. PDT actually keys a lot of it's 'intellisense' features from docblocks and annotations. Not only @return but also @param, @see and sometimes @throw. I'm sure there are others as well. Good luck!

Comment: I also want to say thanks for the quick response.  You answered me within a half hour of my posting.  I had posted this same question on the eclipse.org forum more than a day ago and I **still** haven't received a response there.